# Use list of partial file names in txt to copy files from one folder to another

Tags: powershell, filesystems, file-transfer, file-management

I have a large number of images stored in a single folder and sorted through them to choose which to copy to certain folders such as "scenery" or "technical" and created a list of partial filenames for each folder in a text file. 
eg. Scenery.txt

> ```
> 4811
> 4819
> 4820
> ```

These are the unique file numbers which are part of the full filenames, for example:

```
C:\Users\drewb\Pictures\2018_08_Inuvik\All\DSC_4811.jpg
```

I have a script in powershell which has worked for me when I had a list of the full filenames listed in a .txt file but to save time due to a larger number of photos I only wrote the image number. I'm hoping there's a way to create an array of this list and feed it as a variable in the full filename in a loop, but any suggestion is appreciated.

The code which worked for me with the full names in the .txt was

```
Get-Content C:\Users\drewb\Pictures\2018_08_Inuvik\Technical.txt | ForEach-Object {copy-item $_ C:\Users\drewb\Pictures\2018_08_Inuvik\Technical}
```

SOLVED: 
I solved it by concatenating the file path to the names and the file extension in excel then used used the PS script I previously used. However, I feel like there must be a more direct way this could be scripted.

Comment: are the image numbers in the file each on a new line or are they next to each other?

Comment: I believe you need a smarter tool than just CMD or powershell.

Comment: The image numbers are on each new line. Do you have any ideas on what i could use?

Comment: @DrewBranson I'm not understanding the question 100%. which pictures must go in which folder? you want to create a folder e.g `4811` and all Files which have `4811` in their FileName should go into this folder? please elaborate a bit, by editing your question

Comment: You question needs a little more clarity. Seems like Powershell is a good solution, but it's tough to answer without another explanation. You could extract all the numeric values from your images, if they are all named the same way as your example image, like this: `gci | select -ExpandProperty BaseName | % { $_.Split('_')[1] }`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer

If the current directory contains pictures whose file names follow the same pattern `DSC_XXXX.jpg` (where `XXXX` is a number) and a file named `Technical.txt` containing some of these numbers, the following command would copy to the `Technical` folder (assuming it exists in the current directory) all files for which a number is provided in the `Technical.txt` file:

```
Get-Content Technical.txt | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item "DSC_$_.jpg" Technical }
```

If the `Technical.txt` and picture files and the `Technical` directory are not in the current directory, full or relative paths have to be provided, for example:

```
Get-Content c:\path1\to\Technical.txt | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item "c:\path2\to\pictures\DSC_$_.jpg" c:\path3\to\Technical }
```

#### Explanation

- The `"DSC_$_.jpg"` expression in the command is used to generate the picture file name from the number that was read from the `Technical.txt` file, which is the current pipeline object (i.e. `$_`). It simply adds `DSC_` as a prefix and `.jpg` as the extension.
- [Get-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) reads the content of the `Technical.txt` file.
- [ForEach-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) executes its script block arguments (enclosed in curly braces, i.e. `{}`) for each object in the pipeline, in this case, each line of text returned by `Get-Content`.

#### Testing this solution (online or locally)

The easiest is to try [this solution online](https://tio.run/##pZJNS8NAEIbv@RVDUHra0MYe/AChpo16acEWvBTauE6SLZvdsJnQBvW3x40hUOyHBy/LwvvOzLvPbK63aIoUpaynuGXPhBmwRZUjjIVBTtpUwCbGaDPiJLSCuZCoSFaBViRUieAtCQtaLpCnSvBIwifokpgqpXRm9hLags40nger4fVg4G3y5A5OqP5Z9epHPdV5eLb25pzq99vObhNwrRp7c/p9F@4PHunRjupXIwjZky4I3AeMtUHAHfLSckmAUgSusyxS77euk3AB7Uz2Yh2m6IZbWpcQWlbTKEPH2W@5Vg1jCxt0DL1jCXq28yMS63zHPM6fDhsh1GYS8ZTN3jZ25/ABgc6r9jO4e5AuVg0i93DlX7@Tj2JC808adf0N).

Otherwise, the following snippet can be used to create *in the current directory* a `test` folder containing an example `Technical.txt` file and fake picture files following the pattern mentioned in this answer along with an empty `Technical` directory (**be careful**: you have to change `.\test` to something else if you already have a `test` folder in the working directory:

```
mkdir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue .\test\Technical
Out-File .\test\DSC_4811.jpg; Out-File .\test\DSC_4812.jpg; Out-File .\test\DSC_4813.jpg;
Out-File .\test\DSC_4814.jpg; Out-File .\test\DSC_4819.jpg; Out-File .\test\DSC_4820.jpg;
"4811`n4819`n4820" > .\test\Technical.txt
```

(In the third line, `` `n `` represents an end of line character (the back-tick (`` ` ``) is an [escape character](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters) in PowerShell).

It generates the following files:

```
.\test\DSC_4811.jpg    .\test\DSC_4812.jpg    .\test\DSC_4813.jpg
.\test\DSC_4814.jpg    .\test\DSC_4819.jpg    .\test\DSC_4820.jpg
.\test\Technical.txt
```

After the command provided as an answer is executed (`Get-Content .\test\Technical.txt | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item ".\test\DSC_$_.jpg" .\test\Technical }`), the files are:

```
.\test\DSC_4811.jpg              .\test\DSC_4812.jpg              .\test\DSC_4813.jpg
.\test\DSC_4814.jpg              .\test\DSC_4819.jpg              .\test\DSC_4820.jpg
.\test\Technical.txt
.\test\Technical\DSC_4811.jpg    .\test\Technical\DSC_4819.jpg    .\test\Technical\DSC_4820.jpg
```

To clean up:

```
ri -Recurse .\test
```